# What is x5c? And how to get a x5c?

Tags: ios, api, jwt, in-app-purchase, in-app-purchase-receipt

x5c:

> The JSON Web Signature (JWS) header parameter that contains the certificate chain that corresponds to the key used to digitally sign the JWS.

How to get this certificate in IOS in app purchase?